# Single AD/DHCP/DNS Server - multiple subnets

Tags: domain-name-system, subnet

I'm subnetting the small network of our business for management and security reasons. Prior to this I had:

- 172.16.1.0/24

And now I want this:

- 172.16.1.0/24 -> corporate LAN
- 172.17.0.0/24 -> management of servers
- 172.17.1.0/24 -> hosting - managed services
- 172.17.2.0/24 -> game servers hosting
- 172.17.127.0/24 -> storage resources
- 172.17.128.0/20 -> hosting - servers (VPS, apps, etc)

I have a pfSense router between those subnets. All of the subnets have access to the Internet.

What I want to know is if there is a possibility to have one Active Directory, DNS and DHCP service running on a single server in the managed services subnet (172.17.1.0/24), and make it reachable by the subnets.

I already looked at DHCP relay, I guess I'll have to use it, but what about DNS and Active Directory? Anything to do on the router?

Comment: What is the issue? Servers don't use in generally a DHCP lease. You only need to take care of the routing of each net, in case you only use CIDR 24 instead of 16 on a 172 network. And the Shortly answer would be, it may be possible depends on the use. but since it looks a bit offtopic be more specific to your question.

Comment: Sure, servers don't use DHCP, but since I want the created VPS to be reachable after their installation, I have to use DHCP.
Regarding the routing, it's working fine, I can reach each subnet without any trouble.
But what about the DNS? Is there a DNS relay or something like this?

Comment: You have to decide, either you want to use the AD with DNS and DHCP or use a external  DHCP.

Comment: I said I want to use AD/DHCP/DNS on a single server. The question is clear imho: what do I need to do to spread the usage of those services across the subnets I listed above?

Comment: If you would use AD you can descripe and use Locations to split the Subnets. But for This you have to use only AD/DNS/DHCP instead of using a relay on Windows Site.